# workspace shortcuts also move window

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad, workspaces

When I use ctrl + alt + arrow or 4 fingers gestures, it can change workspace as desired or stick the current window to a screen side (or maximize, minimize) according to said arrow.

it looks like both actions are linked to the same shortcut.

I want to change the 'stick window' shortcuts, but they are not listed in Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

How do I change those settings?

Answer (score 0):

By using this link: http://devmartin.com/blog/2016/11/ubuntu-16.04-remap-shortcut-for-windows-aero-snap-like-window-movement-window-tiling/

I saw that those shortcuts can't be edited like others. I had to install compizconfig-settings-manager to edit them.

I set them to Super+arrow and everything works fine now.